# How to split an array in many others arrays with two specific sizes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, chunks

I'm trying to find out if there is a way in splitting an array into many others arrays, but these arrays should have a length of 4 and 8. Like:

```
const someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25];

output newArray = [[1,2,3,4],
                   [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                   [13,14,15,16],
                   [17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
                   [25]];
```

I've seen many solutions to chunk into specific single sizes like:

```
export const chunk = (array, size) => {
  const chunkedArr = [];
  let copiedArr = [...array];
  const numOfChild = Math.ceil(copiedArr.length / size);

  for (let i = 0; i < numOfChild; i++) {
    chunkedArr.push(copiedArr.splice(0, size));
  }
  return chunkedArr;
};
```

which I've tried to "adapt" for my requirements, but had no success.

Any help?
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) along with appropriate indices to achieve this.

```js
const someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25];

let i = 0;
let step = 4;
const newArray = [];
while(i < someArray.length) { 
  newArray.push(someArray.slice(i, i + step));
  i += step;
  step = step == 4 ? 8 : 4;
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: if you change `isFourStep` to `let chunk = 4` and toggle it to 8 (or back to 4) on each iteration you can shorten this quite a bit.

Comment: Note quite I was thinking more along the lines of `let i = 0; let step = 4; const newArray = []; while(i < someArray.length) { newArray.push(someArray.slice(i, i + step)); i += step; step = step == 4 ? 8 : 4; }`.

Comment: @max Amazing, done that. Sometimes things don't click. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation consuming the array with a recursive function:

```js
const someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25];


const iter = (sliceLen, arr, acc = []) =>
 arr.length <= sliceLen 
 ? [...acc, arr.slice(0, sliceLen)]
 : iter(sliceLen === 4 ? 8 : 4, arr.slice(sliceLen), [...acc, arr.slice(0, sliceLen)])
 
 const r = iter(4, someArray)
 
 console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this would be to just swap back and forth between the chunk size for the iteration.

```js
const someArray =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25];

console.log(
  chunk(someArray, 4, 8)
);

function chunk(input, size1, size2){
  const output = [];
  let chunkSize = size1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length;) {
    output.push(input.slice(i).slice(0, chunkSize));
    i += chunkSize;
    chunkSize = (chunkSize === size1 ? size2 : size1);
  }
  
  return output;
}
```